# Connection failed en Xampp, no conecta a phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

Por alguna razon, no puedo conectarme a phpmyadmin usando este codigo. En connect_db.php. Dice que hay un problema de conexion y no da el numero de error.

```
<form method="POST" action =""/> <!-- El formulario en si -->
 <label for="nom"><b>Nombre de usuario</b></label>
 <input type="text" placeholder="Escriba su nombre de usuario" name="nombre" id ="nombre"></input>

<label for="clav"><b>Clave</b></label>
<input type="password" placeholder="Escriba su clave de usuario" name="clave" id ="clave"></input>

<label for="em"><b>Email</b></label>
<input type="text" placeholder="Escriba su email" name="email" id ="email"></input>

<label for="ced"><b>Cedula de identidad</b></label>
<input type="text" placeholder="Escriba su cedula de identidad" name="cedula" id ="cedula"></input>

<input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" class="floated" value="Registrarse"></input>

<div class="container" style="background-color:#f1f1f1">
<button type="Reset" class="floated">Cancelar</button>
</div>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ 
$nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
$clave = $_POST['clave'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$cedula = $_POST['cedula'];

//esto evita que el usario meta datos en blanco
$reqlen = strlen($nombre) + strlen($clave) + strlen($cedula) + strlen($email);

 if($reqlen > 0){
  require('connect_db.php'); //Algo anda mal aca, no logra conectarse
  $clave = md5($clave);    //Convierte la clave en md5

  mysqli_query("INSERT INTO `usuarios` VALUES ('', '$nombre', '$clave', '$email', '$cedula')");
  mysqli_close($link);
  echo 'Se ha registrado exitosamente';

}else{
echo 'Por favor rellene los espacios necesarios';  
}
}
?>
</form>
```

Estoy usando xampp y mysql si preguntan. Debido a este error, no puedo meter datos en la base de datos.

El codigo en connect_db.php:

```
<?php
// Create connection
$link =  mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "prueba");

// Check connection
if (!$link) {
    die('Connection failed: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
}   

//por alguna razon, la conexion falla todo el tiempo
?>
```

Agradezco su respuesta.

Comment: Que se supone tienes en $link? Si son los paramentros de conexión, entonces en tu if($link){..} estas especificando que si se conecta, cierre la conexión, más bien creo que el if debería ser if(!$link){..}. Eso si, depende de lo que tengas en $link.

Comment: Ya arregle esa parte del codigo.

Answer (score 0):

La función esta mal utilizada:

```
mysqli_query("INSERT INTO `usuarios` VALUES ('', '$nombre', '$clave', '$email', '$cedula')");
```

ya que le hace falta la conexión a la base de datos, lo correcto seria:

```
mysqli_query($conexionBD,$consultaSQL);
```

Como recomendación deberías de descartar el uso de estas funciones y empezar a utilizar PDO.

Comment: Gracias por tu aporte, Robert y bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español. Por favor toma el [recorrido del sitio](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour). Para futuras respuestas, te recomiendo leer estos **[pasos para elaborar una buena respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)** y puedes consultar aquí [qué funciones tiene Stack Overflow en Español para que puedas organizar el código o lo que coloques en tus preguntas y/o respuestas](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/a/1453/78). Saludos.

Comment: Ya lo intente y no funciono. Sigue dando connection failed

Comment: puedes mostrar el archivo de conexion a la base de datos?